# Visual Basic 6: How to add Paint handler?

Tags: paint, basic, onpaint

I've inherited a Visual Basic 6 project.  I need to add a Paint handler to a form for some custom graphics, but can't see any way to do this.  I've looked at every option in the Visual Basic development environment and Googled, but there's no clue.  Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by `Paint handler`?

Comment: By "paint handler" I mean a method that's invoked by the paint event to draw on the form.

Comment: I don't think VB6 forms have any such events. Perhaps this will help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19015/Using-NET-Controls-in-VB . The alternative is to write VB6-style event handlers for whatever events are triggering the paint event.